# How to display the link element based on the list items length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

We need to display all the list items if list length more than 4 we need to display "show" link otherwise hide the "show" link.

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2028/)

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul class="scrollbar" ng-class="{'noscrollbar' : scrollBar}">
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}</li>
</ul>
<a ng-click="a()">{{text}}</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names=[
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}];

$scope.showText=true;
$scope.scrollBar=false;
$scope.text='show';
$scope.a=function()
{
alert("call");
$scope.showText=!$scope.showText;
$scope.scrollBar=!$scope.scrollBar;
$scope.text=='show' ? $scope.text='less' : $scope.text='show';

};
}
```

CSS:

```
.scrollbar
{
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:200px;
}

.noscrollbar
{
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

How to display the 'show' link element  based on the list items length

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-show`/`ng-if` here

```
<a ng-click="a()" ng-show="names.length > 4">{{text}}</a>
```

**Note**

If you wanted to use `ng-if` here, then you need to put `text` variable inside a object to ensure Dot rule will get followed.

```
<a ng-click="a()" ng-if="names.length > 4">{{model.text}}</a>
```

Comment: @Mgr does it hepled?